# Can I get a walkthrough on this Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery and I posted a question asking for some help on a topic. Someone kindly helped me out and I highly appreciate it. I just want to know if someone can help me understand what the different parts of this is doing

```
$(".gradeA, .gradeU").find(":checkbox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked === false) { return; }
    var cells = $(this).parent().siblings();
    $(".fields").empty().append($("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
        id: "request_venue",
        name: "request[venue]",
        value: cells[1].innerHTML
    })).append($("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
        id: "request_showdate",
        name: "request[showdate]",
        value: cells[0].innerHTML
    }));    
});
```

what does the find do and the empty and just a quick walk through would be awesome so i can learn from it

Comment: @Floyd - LMGTFY links are banned on SO, for a reason.  They're not at all constructive.

Comment: My bad. I did not know that. Shall remember this, thanks

Comment: @Floyd is that why you hid your LMGTFY behind url minifiers?  While we're on the subject of unhelpful things, RTFM is also right out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".gradeA, .gradeU").find(":checkbox")
```

For all elements that have a class of gradeA or gradeU, find all the checkboxes within the element and apply a click event to them.

```
if (this.checked === false) { return; }
```

If the elements that was clicked is checked off

```
$(".fields").empty().append($("<input type='hidden'>")
```

For all elements with a class of "field", remove all child elements and append an input element.